# Inequality from continuity exercise

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, continuity

I am reading from Courant's book. He gave an example of the continuity of $f(x)=5x+3$ by finding $\delta=\epsilon/5$. He then said that $|x-x_0|$ does not exceed $|y-y_0|/5$, but I don't see how he came up with this inequality.

I know that $|x-x_0|<\epsilon/5$, and that $|y-y_0|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow|y-y_0|/5<\epsilon/5$, but I don't think that that suffices to conclude $|x-x_0|<|y-y_0|/5$.

> ... indeed $|x-x_0|$ is sufficiently small if it does not exceed one-fifth of the value of $|y-y_0|$.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: You are supposed to conclude $|x-x_0|≤|y-y_0|\5$, the inequality mustn't be strict. He said does not exceed, so taking the negation transforms it into a $≤$ sign

Comment: But that doesn't tell us anything. It's just an equality $|y-y_0|/5=|x-x_0|$ which is clear, of course. Why would he transform it to an $\leq$?
Plus he said "is sufficiently small if ...", but it is always the case that $|y-y_0|/5=|x-x_0|$, the size of $|x-x_0|$ doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to say the opposite: $|x-x_0| \ge \frac15|y-y_0|$. You can get this from
$$|y-y_0| = |f(x)-f(x_0)| = |(5x+3)-(5x_0+3)| = 5|x-x_0|$$
and now from $|x-x_0| < \frac\varepsilon5$ you get $|y-y_0| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how the inequality I mentioned holds. I have edited my post for more clarity.

Comment: you*. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

To prove continuity of $f$ at a point $c$, you need to show $\forall ~ \varepsilon >0 \exists ~ \delta >0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(c)|=5|x-c|<\varepsilon$

What he meant is when you choose an arbitrary $\varepsilon$ (note the definition of continuity) , it suffices to set $\delta =\frac{\varepsilon}{5}$ because $|x-c|<\varepsilon/5 \implies 5|x-c|=|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$, proving continuity.

I forgot taking a look at $f(x)$. Indeed it holds because $|5x+3-5c-3|/5=|x-c|$ and obviously $x>x$ cannot hold for any real number.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! I actually do understand why we chose delta like that. My question is not about continuity.